# how to use joining with LinQ To Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this code

```
    var value = (from dc in _context.ContractDetails
                   where dc.EmployeeID == id
                    select dc.Amount);
    return value;
}
```

is it acceptable to do Value.Sum();

Comment: please paste the exception track

Comment: The LINQ returns an `IEnumerable<decimal>` (assuming ContractDetails.Amount is a decimal). But you are assigning it to a `decimal`. Are you looking for a Sum, First, Last, Min, Max, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return the sum it looks like. Instead of having query be a decimal, just let it be what it wants (var, it's really `IEnumerable<decimal>`). Then you can return an aggregate on that. Sum for example

```
var query = from emp in Employees
            join cd in ContractDetails
            on emp.EmployeeID equals cd.EmployeeID
            where cd.EmployeeID == id
            select cd.Amount;
return query.Sum();
```

If this is all it does, then I also feel like you don't need to join at all, and it would be simpler to do

```
var query = from cd in ContractDetails
            where cd.EmployeeID == id
            select cd.Amount;
return query.Sum();
```

... unless you were using the join to test for the existence of an employee in the Employee table as a condition.

Comment: But if we returned decimal, how to implement it in View , I'm using MVC 5

Comment: @Mohammed I think the original question has been answered (twice once with lambdas and once with your original query). Your method can now do exactly what it is called: `public decimal GetSumOfAmount(int id) { }`. Fitting it into your MVC might require you to create a different question with the specific problem you encountered. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your linq statement results in an `IQueryable<Amount>`, you would need to take that result and call `Sum()` on it to get the result you're seeking.

First, isn't there a navigation property you can use (i.e. `Employee.ContracteDetails`) instead of manually joining the two sets?  For example,

```
var sum = _context.Employee
    .Where( e => e.Id == id )
    .Select( e => e.ContractDetails.Sum( cd => cd.Amount ) )
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Second, you're not using any information you need from `Employee`, even your `where` clause references `ContractDetails` alone; why start your query there?  Work with `_context.ContractDetails` instead:

```
var sum = _context.ContractDetails
    .Where( cd => cd.EmployeeId == id )
    .Sum( cd => cd.Amount );
```

Comment: You're using `SingleOrDefault` incorrectly.  It takes a predicate to filter on, not a selector to transform on.

Comment: @juharr - you are correct, rushed through it; should have been `select` then `SingleOrDefault`; corrected